# Use PowerShell to edit an ISO without extracting it

Tags: powershell

I am trying to take an existing and ESXi install ISO and add some files to it, then save it, keeping it bootable.

So far I have tried a few different options, however they all entail extracting the ISO and creating a new one using the Windows ADK tools. These result in the ISO no longer being bootable for installing ESXi. I'm guessing that the ADK tools are meant for a Windows image and not a ESXi image.

I'm using WinISO today to create the ISO files, but I want to automate the creation of the ISO image, as I'm creating 1 ISO per server I'm installing, which could be from 5 servers to a hundred.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mount-diskimage`?

It should allow you to mount the ISO as a drive and interact with it.

Comment: Sadly mount-diskimage can only mount an ISO in read only mode, writing changes only works with VHDs.

Comment: My bad.  I've only worked with vhd(x) and mount-diskimage.